# Actions Tutorial does not work despite SPF validation

Tags: google-schemas

I can't get this to work

https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/apps-script-tutorial

I'm following it verbatim.

When I receive the email from the script (from myself) the Action button is not visible in the inbox.  When I view the original message, I see:

```
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of 3tNFeUggICGscKRPPRWbJTaO.LXVcKRPPRWbJTaO.LXV@maestro.bounces.google.com designates [my network IP address] as permitted sender) client-ip=[my network IP address];
```

I haven't registered yet / our goal is internal emails - but without registering I read sending to myself would work with valid SPF - what am I missing?
thanks!!

Comment: We are using Postini - don't know if that matters - again we're getting SPF validation

Answer (score 1):

The SPF domain must match the email sender domain. If you are sending emails from `myaccount@mydomain.com`, the SPF domain must be `mydomain.com`. Your headers show `3tNFeUggICGscKRPPRWbJTaO.LXVcKRPPRWbJTaO.LXV@maestro.bounces.google.com` as the domain, update your domain configuration to sign emails properly and you should be all set.