# Cannot send Action tests to self despite valid SPF authentication

Tags: email, google-schemas

It seems Google Apps customers cannot test (self-to-self) Actions through Apps Script as outlined in this example: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial#creating_the_project despite having a valid SPF.

According to https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google you can send them self to self, and it should work without pre-registering, provided the email goes through SPF or DKIM authentication.

We have not set up DKIM, but we do have a valid SPF for our domain.  The first part of our SPF record is:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com
```

When I follow the tutorial linked above and I receive the email, the header shows:

```
Received: from mail-it0-x245.google.com (mail-it0-x245.google.com. [2607:f8b0:4001:c0b::245])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id i196si1416642itc.102.2016.06.25.10.03.10
    for <my email address>
    (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
    Sat, 25 Jun 2016 10:03:10 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of 3trluvwgicd0sahffhmrzjqe.bnlsahffhmrzjqe.bnl@maestro.bounces.google.com designates 2607:f8b0:4001:c0b::245 as permitted sender) client-ip=2607:f8b0:4001:c0b::245;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@akrf-com.20150623.gappssmtp.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of 3trluvwgicd0sahffhmrzjqe.bnlsahffhmrzjqe.bnl@maestro.bounces.google.com designates 2607:f8b0:4001:c0b::245 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=3TrluVwgICD0sahffhmrZjqe.bnlsahffhmrZjqe.bnl@maestro.bounces.google.com
Received: by mail-it0-x245.google.com with SMTP id 13so102904690itl.0
    for <my email address>; Sat, 25 Jun 2016 10:03:10 -0700 (PDT)
```

According to the answer on this post ([Actions Tutorial does not work despite SPF validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410435/actions-tutorial-does-not-work-despite-spf-validation)):

```
"The SPF domain must match the email sender domain. 
If you are sending emails from myaccount@mydomain.com, the SPF domain must be mydomain.com.
Your headers show <host>@maestro.bounces.google.com
as the domain, update your domain configuration to sign emails properly and
you should be all set."
```

We have no control over how Apps Script generates email headers, so it seems Apps Script emails will always show @maestro.bounces.google.com.

Which finally brings my question: How can we test Actions via Apps Script if we cannot control the header? Apps Script triggered emails will always go through maestro.bounces.google.com, not [our domain].

Ultimately our goal is to use Actions entirely within our domain, and most likely through Apps Script each time.  It would be great if Google Apps customers could allow Actions to pass (locked down for emails sent within the domain) through GA Control Panel, versus having to follow the very necessary restrictions imposed for domain-to-domain.

If there is another way for me to test this or something I've overlooked, please advise.  Thanks!

Comment: I have also tried sending myself Actions through use of C# system.net.mail to send email through smtp.google.com from our domain.  Unfortunately (ironically?) when you send a message from / to the same email address, this bypasses SPF headers altogether.  Only when I send from userA@mydomain.com to userB@mydomain.com will SPF headers appear.  So it looks like I cannot do self-to-self testing through Apps Script or .NET.  If there is a third alternative please let me know. thanks again for reading through all of this!

Comment: it seems to only work if you use a gmail.com account. You could always try registering your Google Apps domain so you could send markup internally (aaa@mydomain.com to bbb@mydomain.com). Just make sure to state you have a Google Apps domain and that you would like to use it internally when filling out the registration form.

Comment: Franco - thanks so much - you nailed the issue entirely: I hadn't tried on my personal Gmail. I don't have any specific Actions or use yet, as I'm simply trying to understand the basics, but maybe they will let me at least register our domain to be whitelisted so self-to-self emails work the way they do on gmail.com.  Again - thanks!  I wish I could mark this best answer!

Comment: No problem. You can also use this http://gmail-actions.appspot.com instead of Apps Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action tests that are not pre-registered are only testable self-to-self if you send them from personal (gmail.com) accounts.  In order to make them work from a Google Apps for Work account, you currently need to register as if you were sending to someone else.

I've asked Google to open up this functionality so folks using work accounts can follow the tutorials, but if you are just learning this area, for now it is best to use a personal Gmail account.

Thanks Franco - your comment was the right answer but I could not see a way to mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Please try [testing your schemas](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema) to see if your markup is working correctly end-to-end using the [Email Markup Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/) tool.

Once the markup is tested end-to-end with this technique and you are ready to launch your integration to production, check [Registering with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) for the next steps.

Please note that you can only ignore the registration requirements if all emails where the sender and the recipient are the same account. Otherwise, you have to check [Registering with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google).

Comment: Thanks Teyam.  The only thing is that I'm following Google's own tutorial verbatim: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial#creating_the_project : It says "As explained in Registering with Google, all schemas you send to yourself will be displayed in Gmail, so the email sent by the script can be used to ignore the registration requirements for testing purposes."  If Google's own tutorial says you do not need to register after following its steps, they need to bypass the restriction when using Apps Script verbatim from the tutorial.  Or say the example must be registered

Comment: As stated in [Registering with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) "All schemas you send to yourself (from x@gmail.com to x@gmail.com)...". If you may have noticed, the sender and the recipient are the same account. :)